# Can I tell Excel to keep an automated quadratic model y>= 0, without trying to run a manual model?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

1. I am trying to create a quadratic model in Excel with tennis ranks data.
2. When running the automatic model trendline function it gives me a model with negative y values, which can obviously not occur for ranks.
3. How do I tell Excel to keep model y-values >=0?

Thank you!

Comment: according to ur data.. that quadratic model IS the best fit excel can find.. | if u need the automated model to shift.. u'll need to change the data.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot below/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98H2IX1ACiyUf3l4v?e=lb8hCL) refer.

[image: Screenshot]

There are several advantages to understanding the formulation / construct of the quadratic trend.  For instance, replicating the 'automatic trend' using 'linest' as follows provides the user with additional control over the individual terms, and can highlight any graphical errors:

```
=$L$3+$K$3*D3+$J$3*D3^2+$I$3*D3^3
```

This demonstrates a cubic regression (white dots) - which coincide with Excel's 'automatic' trend line.

**Summary of possible issues**

There are several potential issues | remedies you can consider, depending on the goodness of fit, data in question, etc.  A non-exhaustive list of issues you may be encountering include the following:

| Issue | Resolve |
| --- | --- |
| 1) Overfitting | Reduce # terms (e.g. order = 2 instead of 3 etc.) |
| 2) Wrong fit | Attempt Lognormal |
| 3) Negative left | Set Intercept |
| 4) Graphical error | Use scatter chart, sort x values (ascending) |
| 5) Outliers | Various: exclude/adjust, fit separate curve (Extreme Value Theory), manually adjust polynomial terms noting reduction to goodness of fit etc. |

**1) Overfitting**

Trendline options: reduce the order per screenshot:

[image: 1) Overfitting]

**2) Lognormal | Other**

[image: 2) Lognormal]

Transform / consider other fits/curves (you can also place y and x axes on lognormal scale which will automatically remove negatives, although consider outliers and impact upon R-squared / goodness of fit).

**3) Negative left**

[image: 3) Intercept]

In certain circumstances, a negative left may be removed by setting the intercept to an appropriate value.

**4) Graphical error**

It's often easier to use a scatter chart, with x-values ordered per description (regression parameters may be affected otherwise).

**5) Outliers**

It may be the case you're fitting to 1 or 2 outliers.  Consider reducing complexity/number of terms; or adjusting / omitting outliers suitably.  There is an entire branch of statistics that deal with the distribution of extreme values/outliers (Extreme Value Theory - beyond scope of present answer).

**Other remarks**:

Rounding errors in the automatic trend-line function can lead to inaccuracies; human-error in replicating 'automatic trend-line' displayed on the chart - suggesting *linest* / exact formulation preferable).

**Reference(s)**

Data / formulation for first screenshot [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/01/16/excel-trendline-types-equations-formulas/)
Useful video content: [here](https://youtu.be/td-L0siXs7M)